# Постоянно прослушивающий Сокет сервер

Tags: java, сокет

Пишу программу с использованием socket. Пользовался поисковой системой Google, не нашел нормального примера для использования. С socket работаю впервые и поэтому не настолько сильно в них разбираюсь. Логика следующая, есть некий клиент, который постоянно будет отправлять данные в виде string. Я должен создать серверную часть, которая будет постоянно прослушивать, и считывать данные. Делать некие манипуляции и сохранять в базу. Если в течении 30 сек не будет никаких данных, то закрыть связь с этим клиентом, но другие клиенты могут подключаться. Socket должен постоянно работать. Есть у кого-нибудь готовый кусок кода как это реализовать? Выручайте.
**Мой код**

```
public class TRSServerInterface implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = null;
    boolean runner = true;
    String message = "";

    public TRSServerInterface(int port) {
        try {
            //init server socket with port
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 3);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { // default run method of Thread class and Runnable interface

        try {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                //get the input and output streams
                objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                objectOut.flush();
                objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                sendResponse("Connection successful!");
                do {

                    try {
                        message = (String)objectIn.readObject();
                        System.out.println("client>" + message);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                    }

                } while (!message.equals(""));
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                //we must close all open connections 
                objectOut.close();
                objectIn.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void sendResponse(String response) {
        try{
            objectOut.writeObject(response);
            objectOut.flush();
            System.out.println("server>" + response);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Regent просмотрите изменения пжл.

Comment: сделайте `socket` не глобальным. И каждый `socket` отправляйте в отделный `обработчик/поток`. Так же создайте прослушивател  `server.bind(address);` после `server.isBound()` можете  получить `accept`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот часть кода который вам может помочь

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // Starting the listener
        log.info("starting TCP Server, port: " + this.port);

        int index = 0;

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(this.host, this.port);
        server.bind(address);

        if (server.isBound()) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Waitting Client Connection.......");
            }

            /* Continue receiving clients while canWork stays TRUE */
            while (this.canWork) {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug("tcp client: " + index);
                }
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                TCPSession tcpSessionLocal = new TCPSession(socket);
                index++;
                tcpSessionLocal.setTcpConnectionTimeout(tcpConnectionTimeout);
                tcpSessionLocal.start();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("tcp receiver main try-catch error " + ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

тут `tcpConnectionTimeout` поможет закрыть не нужный сокет. А так принимает клиентов без остановки. Можете завершить, задав значение `this.canWork=false`

UPD

Добавляю часть кода класса `TCPSession`

```
public class TCPSession extends Thread {


    // Local variables
    private Socket socket = null;
    private int error_num = Constants.ERR_SUCCESS;
    private int tcpConnectionTimeout = 300000;

    /**
     * A session to read from input stream and pars binary data.
     *
     * @param socket the socket Handle of incoming connection
     */
    public TCPSession(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            this.socket.setSoTimeout(tcpConnectionTimeout);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            log.warn("TimeOut not set");
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                if (!socket.isClosed()) {

                    // Read data from stream
                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                    int firstByte = inputStream.read();

                    int read = 0;
                    while (read != -1) {
                    read = inputStream.read();
                        log.debug("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + String.format(" %02X", read));

                    // Если что то не так, делаете выход из цикла
                    // если read = -1 значит нет больше данных в InputStream

                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Session exception in ERR:" + error_num);
            log.error(Trace.getStackTrace(ioe));
        }

        // Close socket
        if (this.socket != null && !this.socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                this.socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Socket close in ERR:" + error_num);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: TCPSession это стандартный класс джава или мне его самому надо написать? среди стандартных я его не нашел. и да, считываение и отправку ответа мне надо производить внутри while(this.canWork) {}. я прав?

Comment: Это не стандартный класс. Это я сам сделал. а тут как пример дал.

Comment: ну мне это и было интересно как реализовать то, чтобы закрыть свзять с клиентом. в данном случае просто название класса и вызов метода никак не описывают логику этого метода.

Comment: а поток вы закрываете внутри класса `TCPSession` там можете и задержку проверять и что угодно. на ваше расмотрение. Я тут пример дал для того что бы у вас  `которая будет постоянно прослушивать и считывать данные` работало. Тут у вас 2 вопроса из этого такая путеница.

Comment: честно говоря то что вы указали это я и так знал, что внутри while считывать инфо. но главная логика содержится в TCPSession и если бы я знал его как реализовать, то я не задал бы этот вопрос здесь. проблема в том, что я не знаю как правильно закрывать связь с клиентом, но при этом чтобы сервер продолжал работать. в любом случае спасибо

Comment: @JackDaniel проверьте UPD ответа. добавил часть кода TCPSession

Comment: все, теперь ясно. а tcpSessionLocal.start() просто заново открывает сокет для прослушиваю, socket.accept(), я правильно понял?

Comment: @JackDaniel от сокет заново не открывает. Его уже открыл `Socket socket = server.accept();` а `TCPSession` просто берет этот сокет себе `this.socket = socket;` и работает с ним

Comment: ааа да, ошибся) тот старт просто поток запускает. все, понял теперь. спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Возможно будет лучше почитать про простейшую [реализацию](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/ClientServer.html) клиента и сервера.
Там всё подробно описано, сначала разберитесь в принципе работы. То, что вы спрашиваете не трудно реализовать, это можно сделать дополнив код, который находится по ссылке.

А потом, если захотите, то можете воспользоваться кодом человека выше, тем более после прочтения статьи вам будет более понятно то, что вам ответили.

Метод серверного сокета **accept()** будет постоянно ждать клиента и код далее не выполнится, пока клиент не будет найден, а клиент не сможет отправить String строки, пока не подключится к серверу, т.е. в никуда на удачу, что сервер что-то получит, кидать не получится.

Comment: в принципе я разобрался. но у меня появился другой вопрос. всегда ли сервер-клиент работают в режиме запрос-ответ? т.е. нельзя чтобы клиент непереставая отправлял сообщения, а получил бы ответ только в случае ошибки в сообщении, который отправляет клиент? а так получая сообщение от клиента, я должен сразу отправлять ответ. как сделать так, чтобы сервер мог отправить ответ при особых услових.

Comment: Простите, но я не совсем понял, что вы написали. Когда клиент подключился к серверу, то можно делать обмен сообщениями. При использовании метода send, насколько я помню, он должен вернуть количество переданных байт, по этому количеству и можно будет судить о том, передалась ли инфа или нет. А дальше уже можете отправлять ответ об удачной посылке или не отправлять, но учтите, что при большом количестве обмена данными это затормозит работу и без того не быстрой ява-машины. Что вы имели ввиду под особыми условиями?

Comment: вот есть сервер и клиент, так? клиент подключается к серверу через accept. после этого сервер ждет команды от клиента. как только клиент пошлет данные, сервер обрабатывает их и отсылает результаты или ответ о проделанной работе клиенту. но можно ли сделать так, что бы сервер отправлял ответ клиенту только в случае ошибки например, а не каждый раз как проделал работу

Comment: Сервер не обязан ничего отправлять, если вы этого сами не захотите. По ссылке, которую я вам дал, там описано про созданные потоки получения и отправки, через них вы обмениваетесь инфой. Сервер ждёт клиента в методе accept, как клиент подключится, сервер получит сокет для конкретного клиента,  но это не значит, что сервер сам магическим образом что-то будет делать, далее всё зависит от вас и вашей реализации сервера. Если вы хотите, то можете сделать так, что сервер будет давать ответ только после возникновения ошибки, но это немного неправильно.

Comment: В C++ есть более конкретные методы send для передачи и recv для чтения, можете реализовать их подобие для java, просто передавать только ошибку, это не есть хорошо, как минимум вы должны сразу после пересылки ответить клиенту о том сколько байт он получил, чтобы сравнить их и быть уверенным в том, что все ваши байты были переданы, но если у вас не будет слишком большого обена данными между сервером и клиентом, то можете реализовать не просто ответ клиенту в виде количества переданных байт, а передать ту же строку обратно, чтобы клиент точно знал, что пересылка была именно той, как вам надо.

Comment: Допустим у вас большой обмен данными в несколько пакетов. Вам будет необходимо ещё реализовать одну вещь, её можно сделать разными способами, но я предложу вам 1 из них, просто они для разных ситуаций разные, но вам можно будет после получения пакета данных, ответить клиенту об количестве переданных байт, после этого клиент уходит в ожидание обработки этих данных ,потом сервер шлёт данные клиенту о завершении обработки, потом клиент отправляет следующий пакет и т.п. Также придумайте для себя некоторый статический набор переменных, который будут содержать короткие коды ошибок  и операций.

Comment: Мне довольно трудно тут изложить всё вам, слишком мало символов в коментах, легче в скайпе

Comment: по скайпу я щас к сожалению не смогу. у нас будет обмен данными с банком. банк не переставая будет посылать нам данные курсов валют и у каждого сообщения будет ID и если например на сервер придет не последовательный ID (1, 2, 3, 7) то я должен буду остановить прием данных и дать знать клиенту только в этом случае, что передача неправильна и пускай повторит с 4. в принципе я понял что вы имели ввиду. спасибо за помощь еще раз

Comment: Пожалуйста, надеюсь я вас смог помочь.